# Add two $row together in one php echo

Tags: php, echo

I'm not even sure if what I am trying to do is possible, I have a simple php echo line as below..

```
<?php echo $T1R[0]['Site']; ?>
```

This works well but I want to make the "1" in the $T1R to be fluid, is it possible to do something like ..

```
<?php echo $T + '$row_ColNumC['ColNaumNo']' + R[0]['Site']; ?>
```

Where the 1 is replaced with the content of ColNaumNo i.e. the returned result might be..

```
<?php echo $T32R[0]['Site']; ?>
```

Comment: Why dont you use arrays where you make a loop instead auf $T1R, $T2R, ...

Comment: You're using wrong concatenation character. This is no javascript.

Comment: I guess it's not possible in PHP. Use arrays instead as @bub stated

Comment: @Ryan it is possible, read the answer below. And for the OP - using Arrays is designed to ease these sort of issues :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible in PHP. The concept is called ["variable variables"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

The idea is simple: you generate the variable name you want to use and store it in another variable:

```
$name = 'T'.$row_ColNumC['ColNaumNo'].'R';
```

*Pay attention to the [string concatenation operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php). PHP uses a dot (`.`) for this, not the plus sign (`+`).*

If the value of `$row_ColNumc['ColNaumNo']` is `32` then the value stored in variable `$name` is `'T32R'`;

You can then prepend the variable `$name` with an extra `$` to use it as the name of another variable (indirection). The code `echo($$name);` prints the content of variable `$T32R` (if any).

If the variable `$T32R` stores an array then the syntax `$$name[0]` is ambiguous and the parser needs a hint to interpret it. It is well explained in the documentation page (of the variable variables):

> In order to use variable variables with arrays, you have to resolve an ambiguity problem. That is, if you write `$$a[1]` then the parser needs to know if you meant to use `$a[1]` as a variable, or if you wanted `$$a` as the variable and then the `[1]` index from that variable. The syntax for resolving this ambiguity is: `${$a[1]}` for the first case and `${$a}[1]` for the second.

Comment: Nice and detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I meant.. I will spend some time playing with this and let you know how I get on..

Comment: Worked like a dream.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
$T1R[0]['Site'] = "test";

$c = 1;

$a = "T".$c."R";

$b = $$a;

echo "<pre>";
print_r($b[0]['Site']);
```

Or more simpler like this

```
$T1R[0]['Site'] = "test";

$c = 1;

$a = "T".$c."R";

echo "<pre>";
print_r(${$a}[0]['Site']);
```